# Checkbox is not returning false angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular2-forms

```
<div *ngFor="let bookData of allBookData.books">
      <input #bookArray type="checkbox" id="bookArray " name="bookArray " class="form-control" value="bookData.bookname" checked="bookData.book_id == 3"> {{bookData.bookname}}
</div>
```

I have 3 books in allBookData

```
book_id :1 bookname: The Magician
book_id :2 bookname: Rainbow Behind Tree
book_id :3 bookname: Mr Romeo
```

So now I want Mr Romeo checkbox is checked since the **book id == 3**, but all checkboxes are checked. I think my condition in **checked=""** is wrong. What is the correct condition I should do there.

I have also tried this

```
checked ="bookData.book_id == 3 ? true : false"
```

still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `[checked]="expression"`

```
<div *ngFor="let bookData of allBookData.books">
  <input #bookArray type="checkbox" id="bookArray " name="bookArray " class="form-control" value="bookData.bookname" [checked]="bookData.book_id === 3"> {{bookData.bookname}}
</div>
```

---

BTW,  the `value` property is not recommened here, better to use `[(ngModel)]`.